# Service menu on Gnome desktop environment

Tags: linux, gnome, kde-plasma

Is there any way to create a service menu on Gnome?

In kde it's simply a .desktop file placed in $HOME/.kde/share/kde4/services/ServiceMenus/

Does it exist a similar thing in Gnome?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure what the term "service menu" means in KDE land, but if you want to add to the context menu of Gnome's file manager Nautilus, then this link maybe what you are looking for: http://www.linux.com/feature/119603

Comment: yes I need to add to the context menu (I don't know either Nautilus is the default desktop manager...)